# Given a linear transformation $T: V\rightarrow W$, why is range($T$) equal to span($Tv_{1}, Tv_{2}, ..., Tv_{n}$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

Isn't range($T$) equal to the set { $Tv_{1}, Tv_{2}, ..., Tv_{n}: v \in  V$ }? I'm just not sure why the range of T has to be the span of these vectors.

Comment: **Hint**: What's $T(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_nv_n)$?

Comment: Your notation for the set is inconsistent, what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing $\{ \mathbf{v}_k \}_{k=1}^n$ is a basis for $V$?  If so, every linear transformation is determined by its action on a set of basis vectors.  If you want to know where $T$ sends some $ \mathbf{w} \in V$, simply express $\mathbf{w} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \mathbf{v}_k$.  Then we have $T( \mathbf{w} ) = T \left( \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \mathbf{v}_k \right)$, and by the properties linear transformations satisfy, this becomes $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n c_kT( \mathbf{v}_k)$.  In particular, $T( \mathbf{w}) \in \text{Span} \left\{ T( \mathbf{v}_k) \right\}_{k=1}^n$, which means $\text{Range}(T) \subseteq \text{Span} \left\{ T( \mathbf{v}_k) \right\}_{k=1}^n$.

To get the reverse inclusion, suppose $\mathbf{w}' \in \text{Span} \left\{ T( \mathbf{v}_k) \right\}_{k=1}^n$.  Working in reverse to the above, you can find a $\mathbf{w} \in V$ so that $T( \mathbf{w}) = \mathbf{w}'$.  So indeed the two sets in question are equal.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are getting mixed up between the **definition** of the range (that is, a statement of what the word "range" means) and a **theorem** about the range (that is, a fact about the concept of range which goes beyond merely the meaning of the word).

> **Definition**.  If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation, then the range of $T$ is the set
> $$\mathop{\rm range}\nolimits(T)=\{\,T({\bf v})\mid {\bf v}\in V\,\}\ .$$

$ $

> **Theorem**.  If $\{\,{\bf v}_1,\ldots,{\bf v}_n\,\}$ is a spanning set for $V$, then $\{\,T({\bf v}_1),\ldots,T({\bf v}_n)\,\}$ is a spanning set for the range of $V$.
>
> **Proof**.  See Kaj Hansen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, say $z\in V$. Let $z=v_1+v_2+v_3$, then $T(z)\in R(T)$. In particular, $$T(z)=T(v_1+v_2+v_3)=T(v_1)+T(v_2)+T(v_3)\in R(T).$$ But, $$T(v_1)+T(v_2)+T(v_3) \not \in \{Tv_1, Tv_2,....,Tv_n: v_k \in V \text{ for }  1\leq k\leq n \}.$$

The span includes all linear combinations, not just the elements of the basis.