# Defining linear transformations on bases

Tags: linear-algebra

I am going through many of the problems in Linear algebra done right. I have come across many problems that require a linear transformation to be defined on basis vectors of $V$.For instance many problems in the book require finding a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$ where  transformations are defined  on basis vectors for the vector space $V$, sending these basis vectors to arbitrary vectors in $W$. I am having a lot of difficulty knowing when to choose a basis for a vector space and which vectors to send the basis vectors to.

What is the convention for defining a transformation on basis vectors and extending it to a unique map onto the vector space $V$?Can someone tell me why we define transformations on basis vectors so often?Also how do you know when this procedure should be used?

Also, in order to define a transformation uniquely on basis vectors do I have to always choose the same number of vectors in $W$ to be images of the basis vectors in $V$?

When defining maps on basis vectors is the important part about this the ability to map basis vectors into any arbitrary vectors in $W$ whatsoever?

I am really confused on this process an believe mastering it will be vital in achieving success in linear algebra. Can someone clear up confusion I have?

Comment: Maybe you need to draw some pictures of concrete examples. E.g. for a map $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ we only need to know what $\varphi$ does on $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: @QiZhu In order to define a transformation on each of the standard basis vectors, we have to map each vector to an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$?And that's how to define this linear transformation?

Comment: You may find discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239580/given-a-linear-transformation-t-v-rightarrow-w-why-is-ranget-equal-to-sp/2239586) helpful.

Comment: @68e1515 Yes, the map $\varphi$ goes to $\mathbb{R}^2$ after all, so you have to map to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Pick some concrete examples. You should see what $\phi(\lambda (1,0))$ must be e.g., then what $\phi(\lambda (1,0) + \mu(0,1))$ and why this is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Usually undergraduate linear algebra doesn't work with infinite bases, and, I'm my opinion, bases are the most relevant objects of linear algebra. For finite bases, it's even more useful (or at least easier to use in strong results).

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $K$, and let $\beta = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be an ordered basis. We know that any vector $v \in V$ can be described *uniquely* as a linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$; say $v = \alpha_1 v_1 + \ldots \alpha_n v_n$.  Denote, for each vector $v$, the $K$-vector formed by the coefficients $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ as $$[v]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n\end{bmatrix}.$$

Why  did I define all of this? Well, because now linear algebra in $V$ is basically linear algebra in $K^n$. We can say that $V$ and $K^n$ are *isomorphic*. I'll discuss that:

---

Suppose we have a linear map $T\colon V \to V$. It suffices to define the values of $T$ over the base $\beta$. We can see that because $T(v) = T(\,\sum_i {[v]_\beta}_i\,v_i\,)= \sum_i {[v]_\beta}_i\,T(v_i).$ So the values $T(v_i)$, i.e., the valuee of $T$ taken at each element of the basis, are sufficient to determine all the remaining vectors.

Specifically, if $[T(v_i)]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix}a_{1i} \\ \vdots \\ a_{ni} \end{bmatrix}$, try to open by hand what $[T(v)]_\beta$ is. I really mean it, try it! ... and it's
$$[T(v)]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & \ldots& a_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots& \vdots\\a_{n1}& \ldots&a_{nn}\end{bmatrix} [v]_\beta!$$

This matrix is called the *representation of $T$ from $\beta$ to $\beta$*, and it's denoted by $[T]_\beta^\beta$.

I gave you an example so now you can extrapolate. Using another basis $\gamma$ of a $K$-vector space $W$, any linear transformation $T\colon V\to W$ becomes a matrix multiplication, with
$$[T(v)]_\gamma = [T]^\gamma_\beta [v]_\beta.$$

Then you extract the coefficients from the multiplication and you're good to go. In brief, if you have the values a basis from $V$ take over $T$, using linearity (example from the first paragraph after the horizontal rule), you determine uniquely your linear transform. If not only knowing the values $T(v_i)$, but also the values $[T(v_i)]_\gamma$, then, in some sense, $T$ is just a matrix determined by the bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Maybe later you'll see what an isomorphism means in various mathematical subjects: two different objects behave the same way when you look them as structures of the same type. The mapping $v \mapsto [v]_\beta$ is a vector space isomorphism, and we denote that by $V \cong K^n$.

Comment: "Usually undergraduate linear algebra doesn't work with infinite bases" - this might be generalizing to certain education systems. In Germany, infinite bases are usually introduced (with Zorn's Lemma) in the first semester and also immediately dealt with.

Comment: You’re right, I’ve used my personal experience limited to my contry.

Answer (score 0):

A linear transformation $T:V\to W$ is completely determined by its effect on a basis.   The values can be chosen arbitrarily in $W$.  Then extend linearly.

Comment: I feel like I am lost but could you explain what "extend linearly" means?I feel like that is a crucial point of this that I am misunderstanding/

Comment: Extend linearly means take linear combinations.

Comment: Any vector $v\in V$ can be written in terms of basis, say $v=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i e_i$. By linearity, this means $T(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i T(e_i)$. In other words, we can determine the image of $T$ on any vector in $V$ given the image on the basis vectors $(e_i)$.

Comment: Ok.  If $\{v_1,\dots,  v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, say.  Then any $v\in V$ is of the form $v=c_1v_1+\dots +c_nv_n$ for certain scalars $c_i$.  Then define $T(v)=c_1T(v_1)+\dots +c_nT(v_n)$.

Comment: I see @FakeAnalyst56 beat me to the punch.

Comment: @ChrisCuster K..

Comment: Incidentally,  this is true even if $V$ is infinite dimensional.  It is good to keep in mind that there are such things.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually very hard to know the behavior of a function only knowing its value on some points, but for a linear transformation you can get all the information you need only by knowing its value in a basis of the vector space which is its domain. The result I'm talking about is this theorem:

Let V and W be two vector spaces, $V$ with finite dimension, and $\{v_{1}, ..., v_{m}\}$ a basis for V. Then, given $\{ w_{1}, w_{2}, ..., w_{n}\}\subset W$ there exists a unique linear transformation $T: V \to W$ such that $$T(v_{i}) = w_{i}, \quad i=1, 2, ..., n$$

The ideia to prove this is:

- First you define $T: V \to W$ such that if $x = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}v_{i} \in V$ then  $T(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\alpha_{i}w_{i}$.

  - Then you verify that this is a linear transformation (Not too hard, just use the way T is defined), then you verify that $T(v_{i}) = w_{i}$ and finally you verify the uniqueness.

I would recommend you follow this steps with some examples first and then try to prove this result I mentioned.